# Масштабирование текста на ноутбуке

Tags: c++, qt

Веду некий проект, недавно прикупил ноутбук для работы вне дома, сегодня попробовал скомпилировать там свой проект и сильно удивился увидев там полную "смазню":

**[Работа на ноутбуке]**
[image: first]
**[Работа на ПК]**
[image: sec]

ПК: 1920x1080
масштабирование: 100%
23 дюйма

Ноутбук: 1920x1080
масштабирование: 150%
13 дюймов

Знаю что проблему нужно решать как через автомасштабирование, но увы не понимаю как это сделать. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: смотрите в сторону HighDPI awareness

Comment: @VTT пробовал это [High DPI](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html), получилось что окно становится слишком большим также как и его элементы

Comment: Видимо что-то неправильно пробовали. Видимые размеры окна не должны при этом изменятьс.

Comment: @VTT `QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);`, после данной строчки приложение становится уже нечитабельным [Скрин](https://i.imgur.com/JhCvxmm.png)

Comment: возможно это громоздкое решение, но можно для ваших виджетов переопределить resizeEvent и там можно пересчитать размер шрифта для виджета. А так похоже что у вас где-то в стилях жестко задан размер шрифта

Comment: @goldstar_labs а как задать размер "не жестко"? т е задать размер не в pt а в px?